# Adding Custom ImageButton to layout in Android causes error

Tags: android, custom-component

I will start by saying this, while I have some Java training, is my first foray into development for Android.

What I have done is created a custom `ImageButton` called `MapCell` that is basically an `ImageButton` that holds a few extra pieces of information, and it compiles fine.

My problem comes when I want to procedurally create a `MapCell` in the relevant `Activity` and add it to my `TableLayout` which is defined in the xml and has the id 'mapTable'. The relevant bit looks like this:

```
Random randy = new Random();

MapCell n = new MapCell(randy.nextInt(4), this); //the random number is part of my extra info

findViewById(R.id.mapTable).addView((View)n, 20, 20); //add cell to display
```

I get one error out of that: 
`The method addView(View, int, int) is undefined for the type View`

Which to me sounds like utter nonsense. I put that `View` cast in there as desperation after I got this same error with `n` sitting by itself and nothing changed (Obviously my `MapCell` is already a `View` since it extends `ImageButton`).

I hope a new pair of eyes can tell me what this is about, since I've checked for similar problems and I didn't find any quite like this. Let me now if you need to see more code.

Answer (score 0):

The method `findViewById` returns a `View` and the `View` class doesn't have the method `addView`(this method is implemented in the `ViewGroup` and its subclasses). Instead you should write:

```
((TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.mapTable)).addView(n, 20, 20);
```

I've cast the return of the `findViewById` method in a class that actually has the `addView` method.

Comment: Thank you both, casting the found view as a TableLayout solved the issue!

Answer (score 0):

You got this problem because method `findViewById(R.id.mapTable)` returns `View` object.
In android you can't add one View to another.

You can use `addView` function with `ViewGroup`, and all `LinearLayout` (etc.) objects.